# JS React Native - importing local database - with Expo - works only in Web view, not at smartphone

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, react-native, express

i implemented a little app for learning, and imported data from a local database. I realized it with this code:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { Platform, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button, SafeAreaView, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements'
import * as React from 'react';
import { ListItem, Avatar} from 'react-native-elements';
import { Header } from 'react-native-elements';
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { List, Colors } from 'react-native-paper';
import Moment from 'moment'; 

const MyComponent = () => {
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(true); 
}
const handlePress = () => setExpanded(!expanded); 

export default class Db extends React.Component {
    state = {
      data: [], 
    }

    
    componentWillMount() {    //load data from a remote endpoint (where to instantiate the network request)
      this.fetchData(); 
    }
    fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/Ph'); 
      const json = await response.json(); 
      this.setState({data: json}); //js object notation
    }
    
    keyExtractor = (x, i) => i //extract item

    
  
    renderItem = ({ item }) => ( 

        
                        <List.Section> 
                        <List.Accordion 
                            
                            theme = {{colors: { primary: '#00A1DE'}}}
                            style= {{ backgruondColor: '#00A1DE' }}
                            titleStyle = {styles.titleContainer}
                             title = {item.Name}
                           
                            
                            left= { props => <List.Icon {...props} icon = "account"  /> }>
                                <List.Item 
                                
                                titleStyle={styles.textContainer}
                                title= {item.Geburtsdatum}  left= { props => <List.Icon {...props} icon = "cake-variant"  /> }></List.Item>
                                <List.Item 
                                 
                                titleStyle={styles.textContainer}
                                title={item.hobbies} left= { props => <List.Icon {...props} icon = "table-tennis"  /> }></List.Item>
                                  </List.Accordion>
                                </List.Section>
    )
      render() {
        return (
            <FlatList 
              keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
              data = {this.state.data}
              renderItem = { this.renderItem }
            />
        )
      }
     
  
  }

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    textContainer: {
      flex: 1,
      height: '90%', 
      width: '90%', 
    }, 
    titleContainer: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
       
        
        
    }
    
  });
```

This works well with the Expo web view, but when I scan the QR Code from my Iphone, the data are not shown. Only footer and header with bottom menue...
I get also the yellow warning because of my ComponentWillMount - function. But do not know, if this is the real reason for my problem. What do you think, why it does not work on my Iphone? I am using the newest expo Version, the newest React Native version and so on... The Code above works well with the Web View from Expo...

Answer (score 0):

Add you IP address instead of `localhost`

1.) Run `cmd`

2.) type `ipconfig`

3.) Scroll Down to `IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.**.**`

4.) Copy this IP and replace it in place of `localhost`

5.) Done

Get your IP like this

[image]

So Suppose if your IPv4 address is - 192.168.100.84 then

Your `fetch` should look like this

```
await fetch('http://192.168.100.84:3000/Ph');
```

Your component should look like this..Notice I've used Function component here

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import {
  Platform,
  FlatList,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
import { ListItem, Avatar } from 'react-native-elements';
import { Header } from 'react-native-elements';
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { List, Colors } from 'react-native-paper';
import Moment from 'moment';

const BaseURL = '192.168.100.84'; // Here your IPv4 address

export default function App() {
  const [Data, setData] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`http://${BaseURL}:3000/Ph`);
    const json = await response.json();
    setData(json);
  };

  const keyExtractor = (x, i) => i; //extract item

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <List.Section>
      <List.Accordion
        theme={{ colors: { primary: '#00A1DE' } }}
        style={{ backgruondColor: '#00A1DE' }}
        titleStyle={styles.titleContainer}
        title={item.Name}
        left={(props) => <List.Icon {...props} icon="account" />}>
        <List.Item
          titleStyle={styles.textContainer}
          title={item.Geburtsdatum}
          left={(props) => (
            <List.Icon {...props} icon="cake-variant" />
          )}></List.Item>
        <List.Item
          titleStyle={styles.textContainer}
          title={item.hobbies}
          left={(props) => (
            <List.Icon {...props} icon="table-tennis" />
          )}></List.Item>
      </List.Accordion>
    </List.Section>
  );

  return (
    <FlatList
      keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
      data={Data}
      renderItem={renderItem}
    />
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    height: '90%',
    width: '90%',
  },
  titleContainer: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but did not change anything. Still blank screen on the tab...

Comment: In your browser `Chrome` or any other browser go to `'http://YOUR_IPv4_ADDRESS:3000/Ph'` and see what you get

Comment: In my browser it works, i get the database

Comment: But not in the smartphone... dont you think it is a problem with the componentWillMount function?

Comment: thank you very much but still does not shown app in smartphone, only in browser

Comment: What is your IPv4 address

Comment: my actual Ip adress is 192.168.2.113. The code from github is old. I used your code with my actual ip adress for db.js

Comment: So if you go to this address -> `http://192.168.2.113:3000/Ph`..then are you getting correct output?..If yess then your `router.js` is correct

Comment: yes I get the same correct output when i do it with localhost. no difference